# ShareDialog Facebook in Custom Dialog - Android

Tags: android, facebook, dialog

I want use `ShareDialog` of Facebook in `Custom Dialog`, but when initialize I can't set context value to new ShareDialog.

```
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(.......); //getContext() not working
```

I need way resolve :(

Answer (score 0):

Kindly pass activity context in the builder, as opposed to the getContext. If using in the Activity , use like

```
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(MyActivity.this);
```

if using it in a fragment

```
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(getActivity);
```

Comment: I want to use it in Custom Dialog :(

Comment: Ohh, I thought it as an initialization problem